# MySQL: How to list all users that do not have access to an existing database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a bit of "spring cleaning" on 3 different mySQL servers (running 5.0.51a-24+lenny5-log, 5.5.54-0+deb7u2 and 5.6.35) with hundreds of databases and many hundreds of users.

So I am looking for a query that returns a list of users, that do not have access to any existing database on the server.

If I look in the `mysql.user`, I can see all the users on the server. So far so good. Now, if I look in `mysql.db` I can see their relation to the databases. So I figured that getting the result, could be as simple as:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM mysql.`user` tblusers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM mysql.`db` tbldbrelation
                     WHERE tblusers.User = tbldbrelation.User)
```

However since relations aren't updated, when a database is deleted (as far as I can tell), looking at those two thing alone, will only get me system, service and root users, etc. I need another approach. Obviously `show databases;` will return all databases currently on the server. But how can take that into account - so that I get a list of users, that do not have access to any of the existing specific database(s)?

Comment: Please provide the complete MySQL server version you have installed

Comment: It's on 3 different server, running `5.0.51a-24+lenny5-log`, 
`5.5.54-0+deb7u2` and `5.6.35` respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to do this, using a relatively simply query that doesn't rely on third party tools - and is supported across MySQL versions - at least 5.0.51a through 5.6.35, which is I am running.

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER
FROM mysql.user a
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM mysql.db b
            WHERE b.User = a.User
            AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT schema_name 
                FROM information_schema.schemata c
                    WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.Db,'\_',1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.SCHEMA_NAME,'_',1)
                    OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.Db,'_',1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.SCHEMA_NAME,'_',1)                                           
            )
    )
```

This will query the `mysql.user` for users which also exist in `mysql.db`, but doesn't have a schema set in the `schema_name` table. The result will be a list of users.

This may have to be customized a little for your specific setup though. A few notes:

- I have made it DISTINCT (`SELECT DISTINCT USER`), as many of my users have multiple logins
  from different locations (i.e. user@123.123.123.123, user@localhost,
  etc). I just wanted one entry out for each. You may want something
  else. EDIT: More useful for most situations would be something like `SELECT CONCAT(USER, "@", HOST)` instead
- The way we structure our table and user names, I have a lot of users
  and tables that contain an underscore (`_`) in the name. (Users are usually created as "domainname_tld" and databases as "domainname_tld_subdomain"). And due to
  the way in which some of these have been created via a script, the
  underscore is sometimes escaped with a backslash (`\`) in the
  actually database name, but not in the schema. That is the reason for my use of the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` method in the final WHERE statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [Percona Toolkit's pt-show-grants](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-show-grants.html) to dump out all my users and their privileges. Then look for users that don't have any privileges except `USAGE`.

For example, I just created a dummy user named `dummy` on my local MySQL instance, but did not GRANT the user any privileges on any database.

The output of pt-show-grants:

```
$ pt-show-grants h=127.0.0.1
-- Grants dumped by pt-show-grants
-- Dumped from server 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP, MySQL 8.0.0-dmr at 2017-02-25 18:35:54
-- Grants for 'dummy'@'127.0.0.1'
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `dummy`@`127.0.0.1`;
-- Grants for 'mysql.sys'@'localhost'
GRANT SELECT ON `sys`.`sys_config` TO `mysql.sys`@`localhost`;
GRANT TRIGGER ON `sys`.* TO `mysql.sys`@`localhost`;
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `mysql.sys`@`localhost`;
-- Grants for 'root'@'localhost'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The mysql.sys user and root user are standard on MySQL 8.0. The lines above show that dummy has USAGE privilege, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was a challenge to answer, but at the end, even we got a "simple" query to show what user accounts do not have any kind of privileges assigned (yes, no privilege at all), and used it to clean our DB :)

Now to understand the query, let it split up to a certain level

First level, list every user not having column level access.

```
SELECT C.User FROM mysql.user C LEFT JOIN mysql.columns_priv ON ( mysql.columns_priv.User = C.User ) WHERE (Column_priv=0 OR Column_priv IS NULL) AND mysql.columns_priv.Db IS NULL
```

Second level, list users who do not have table level privileges, and only users who do not have column level access either.

```
SELECT B.User FROM mysql.user B LEFT JOIN mysql.tables_priv ON ( mysql.tables_priv.User = B.User ) WHERE
mysql.tables_priv.Db IS NULL AND (Table_priv=0 OR Table_priv IS NULL) AND (Column_priv=0 OR Column_priv IS NULL)
AND B.User IN (
    SELECT C.User FROM mysql.user C LEFT JOIN mysql.columns_priv ON ( mysql.columns_priv.User = C.User ) WHERE
    (Column_priv=0 OR Column_priv IS NULL) AND mysql.columns_priv.Db IS NULL)
```

Third level, list users who do not have database level privileges, and list only those who don't have access on the previous two queries.

```
SELECT A.User FROM mysql.user A LEFT JOIN mysql.db ON ( mysql.db.User = A.User ) WHERE
mysql.db.Db IS NULL
AND A.User IN (
    SELECT B.User FROM mysql.user B LEFT JOIN mysql.tables_priv ON ( mysql.tables_priv.User = B.User ) WHERE
    mysql.tables_priv.Db IS NULL AND (Table_priv=0 OR Table_priv IS NULL) AND (Column_priv=0 OR Column_priv IS NULL)
    AND B.User IN (
        SELECT C.User FROM mysql.user C LEFT JOIN mysql.columns_priv ON ( mysql.columns_priv.User = C.User ) WHERE
        (Column_priv=0 OR Column_priv IS NULL) AND mysql.columns_priv.Db IS NULL)
)
```

Third level, checking for anyone who has access on a database level, and list only who don't have table/column level access.

And finally.

```
SELECT mysql.user.Host, mysql.user.User
FROM mysql.user WHERE mysql.user.User IN (
    SELECT A.User FROM mysql.user A LEFT JOIN mysql.db ON ( mysql.db.User = A.User ) WHERE
    mysql.db.Db IS NULL
    AND A.User IN (
        SELECT B.User FROM mysql.user B LEFT JOIN mysql.tables_priv ON ( mysql.tables_priv.User = B.User ) WHERE
        mysql.tables_priv.Db IS NULL AND (Table_priv=0 OR Table_priv IS NULL) AND (Column_priv=0 OR Column_priv IS NULL)
        AND B.User IN (
            SELECT C.User FROM mysql.user C LEFT JOIN mysql.columns_priv ON ( mysql.columns_priv.User = C.User ) WHERE
            (Column_priv=0 OR Column_priv IS NULL) AND mysql.columns_priv.Db IS NULL)
        )
) AND CONCAT(Select_priv,Insert_priv,Update_priv,Delete_priv,Create_priv,Drop_priv,Reload_priv,Shutdown_priv,Process_priv,File_priv,Grant_priv,References_priv,Index_priv,Alter_priv,Show_db_priv,Super_priv,Create_tmp_table_priv,Lock_tables_priv,Execute_priv,Repl_slave_priv,Repl_client_priv,Create_view_priv,Show_view_priv,Create_routine_priv,Alter_routine_priv,Create_user_priv,Event_priv,Trigger_priv,Create_tablespace_priv) NOT LIKE '%Y%'
```

List only those who do not have global accesses assigned and matches the criteria on the other sub-queries.

"Pretty straight"

**EDIT:** Please give feedback, as this query was tested on 5.5 version only.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent and detailed suggestion. It ran fine on the two newer of the three servers (5.5 and 5.6). The older server (running 5.0) however, returned an "Unknown Column"-error. The reason being that `Event_priv`, `Trigger_priv` and `Create_tablespace_priv` do not exist in `mysql.user` in this version of MySQL. And leaving out those 3 columns in the CONTAT(), simply caused the query to run for 20+ min. after which my client (SQLYog) just lost the connection to the server. I didn't investigate the matter further - the reason mainly being my next point (separate comment)

Comment: The query returns users that has no relation to any database, i.e. no priviliges. And this works fine if I, say, create a user and doesn't grant it access to any database. Then I shows up in the result. However let's try another scenario, which is what I am dealing with...

Create a new users and a new database for this user to access - and grant him said access. Delete the database (leaving the user). Then you have a users which doesn't have access to any _existing_ database, but still appears in `mysql.db`. As such the user will not be returned, Leaving us back at square one :( Ideas?